# Is there any way to access wordpress function with external DB connection?

Tags: wordpress

I need to fetch data of ABC wordpress site in another XYZ wordpress site. I created one file in XYZ site's root directory and used below code to make db connection with ABC wordpress site from where i need data.

```
$wpdbNew = new wpdb('abc_db_user', 'abc_password', 'abc_host', 'localhost');
```

The connection is successful but i am not able to access basic wordpress function like - get_the_title($postid);

Please someone let me know that how can i access wordpress function with external DB connection.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MrSaints/8209879

Answer (score 0):

If your connections is fine and as far as you have enough privilege in DB you can access all functions.

Comment: I am just able to access functions related to query like $wpdb->get_results and not wordpress basic function to get title and permalink.